# Is it possible to isolate which process caused data corruption on hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ntfs

I have windows 7 (64 bits) installed on a hard drive along with other systems(windows and linux , that can see mutually other OS partitions)...when i run one of the other systems there is no data corruption but when i run windows 7 it is often a chkdsk screen that appears after system reboot and it happens usually that important files are lost (not to mention files  corrupted by chkdsk itself and bad sectors that are "eating" up to 1Mo !).

I can say from this that this is not a hardware problem but rather a software problem and i think even that this is a hidden program(such as a rootkit) on Windows 7 . I ended up with a conclusion that  this happens when the system is trying to shutdown( i always type 'fsutil dirty query c:' to check the disk state) but as this is happening when the system is becoming out of reach i can not even debug it(i hope to find some processes that the OS cannot stop) and system logs do not show something of relevant.
I know that the last thing that can write on disk sectors is "ntfs.sys" and that processes are unaware of low data writing or retrieval mechanism (the well-known concept of abstarction) but i suspect that rootkits or poorly built processes can do much harm to hard disk than it was possible with the old monolithical systems... i know it's weird but  my question is :

**can we isolate the process that told ntfs.sys to write on a given  sector ?**

Comment: `when i run [Linux] there is no data corruption but when i run windows 7 it is often a chkdsk screen that appears after system reboot and it happens usually that important files are lost. … i think that this is a hidden program(such as a rootkit) on Windows 7` Wouldn’t it be the other way around? Something in Linux is corrupting the drive so when you boot into Windows, it detects the corruption, but when you shut down Windows, it is fine so there is no corruption when you boot into Linux.

Comment: Have you scanned your disk at a low level for defects (Spinrite, HDD Regenerator etc)? What do your IDE SMART statistics say? If the disk surface is bad/weak and the controller has not yet mapped out those sectors all kind of problems can occur.

Comment: When does the corruption occur? When you stop Windows and start Linux? Or when you stop Linux and start Windows? Or when you restart Windows? Or when you restart Linux? Does Linux see the corruptions? Or does only Windows see the corruptions?

Comment: Normally processes work at a higher Level file Interface, they do not write disc sectors. Also for writing disc sectors you Need admin rights that processes normally don't have. Because of this I am quite sure that you do not have a Problem with some process but a Hardware or a Driver issue (Windows or Linux).

Comment: @Werner and @Jan; to say the truth i didn't check for the hardware but if the hardware was responsible then at least one of the other systems could report a problem with the disk when it is run alone many times.Data corruption happens when i work with win7 without switching to other OS and of course when i run linux after win7 data corruption is reported.The command "sfc /scannow" don't report any issue so i don't think drivers are corrupted.I'm hoping that someone knows how to reverse calls chain for file system as this can be helpful to track rootkits ,although this may seem impossible.